# Why I can't SSH key authenticate without VNC login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty, vnc

I run a vServer with the newest Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version and openssh. I have activated the pubkey authentication like:

```
RSAAuthentication        yes
PubkeyAuthentication     yes
AuthorizedKeysFile       %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and disabled the password authentication. For the connection I use Putty on a Windows PC and Pageant for the key holding. The `~/.ssh` folder I set to `chmod 700` and the `authorized_keys` (containing the public key in one line) to `chmod 600` as suggested.

All together works great as long as my VNC remote access is activated and I am logged in to the related Unix account. But when I switch VNC off I get the Putty message:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server
>   sent: publickey)

Why is that? Do I do something wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your setup, but it sounds to me almost like the VNC session is interacting with pageant to lock and unlock your private key.  See if you can manually unlock the key in pageant. (Note I'm a Linux person and don't know much about pageant)

Comment: I guess it's because of the vServer system. When I use the given Ubuntu distribution of my provider every SSH and network setting seems to work.